# Changing UIButton background color

Tags: objective-c

I am creating buttons programmatically. I want to change button background color while touching up inside again it has to set back to its usual color after lifting up our finger.....

```
nine = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[nine setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 105, 65, 40)];
[nine setTitle:@"9" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nine setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[nine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(clickDigit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:nine];
```

// to change background color

```
-(void)changeButtonBackGroundColor:(id) sender
{
    [nine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
```

Here changeBackgroundColor method was created to change color of that button . it changes color.

Comment: "Touch Up" is equal to lifting your finger.

Comment: So... what's the exact question? Did you write methods for the actions you registered? If so, could you add that code.

Comment: Check this post https://somethingaboutios.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/uibutton-backgroundcolor-for-uicontrolstateselected/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't know if this relates to your question but:
this

```
[nine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

should be

```
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Edit:
Change this

```
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];
```

and add the method:

```
- (void)resetButtonBackGroundColor: (UIButton*)sender {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
}
```

Comment: This method causes to change color but its not coming back to cyan color after lifting up finger

Comment: You need to also reset the color for `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` otherwise if you drag your finger off the button the color doesn't reset.

Comment: @dasdom Please edit your (great answer) and add `[self addTarget:self action:@selector(resetButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchCancel];`

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two options..

**First:**

You can put the *[nine setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];* inside "clickDigit" (and like dasdom said rename to sender and change to (UIButton*)sender)..

Change

```
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

to

```
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

and the method "changeButtonBackGroundColor"

```
[sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
```

**Second**

create universal UIControlEvents

```
[nine addTarget:self action:@selector(changeButtonBackGroundColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];

-(void)changeButtonBackGroundColor:(UIButton*) sender{
if ([sender.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor redColor]]){
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
}else{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];        
}}
```

*I didn't try this code*