# change button background color when clicked

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I create a button and I want to change its color when the user clicked on. I saw the option "setimagebackground... forstate...", but there is no other option for changing the background color. I have change values of y button in viewdidload and when I use "settint color:[uicolor redcolor]" nothing happened.
How can I fix it??
Here is my code:

```
    button1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor purpleColor]CGColor];
    button1.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
    button1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    button1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f; 
    [button1.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]CGColor];
    [button1 setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor cyanColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button1 setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

thanks!

Comment: see this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948106/how-can-i-change-the-default-color-of-the-button-on-iphone

Comment: there is no option to do it without an image?

Comment: There is an answer in this post. works well

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737503/changing-uibutton-background-color

Answer (score 4):

With Image:

```
[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redButton.png"]];
```

Without Image:

```
[button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor] ];
```

With this you can get  rounded borders:

```
     CALayer * layer = [button1 layer];     
     [layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
     [layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
     [layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
     [layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
     button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

For the selected state subclass UIButton in this way:

In .h file:

```
@interface MyButton : UIButton 
{
@private
    NSMutableDictionary *backgroundStates;
@public

}

- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *) _backgroundColor forState:(UIControlState) _state;
- (UIColor*) backgroundColorForState:(UIControlState) _state;

@end
```

In .m file:

```
#import "MyButton.h"


@implementation MyButton

- (void) setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *) _backgroundColor forState:(UIControlState) _state {
    if (backgroundStates == nil) 
        backgroundStates = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [backgroundStates setObject:_backgroundColor forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_state]];

    if (self.backgroundColor == nil)
        [self setBackgroundColor:_backgroundColor];
}

- (UIColor*) backgroundColorForState:(UIControlState) _state {
    return [backgroundStates objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:_state]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Touches

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UIColor *selectedColor = [backgroundStates objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIControlStateHighlighted]];
    if (selectedColor) {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"EaseOut"];
        self.backgroundColor = selectedColor;
    }
}

- (void) touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    UIColor *normalColor = [backgroundStates objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIControlStateNormal]];
    if (normalColor) {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"EaseOut"];
        self.backgroundColor = normalColor;
    }
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    UIColor *normalColor = [backgroundStates objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:UIControlStateNormal]];
    if (normalColor) {
        CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
        [animation setType:kCATransitionFade];
        [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
        [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"EaseOut"];
        self.backgroundColor = normalColor;
    }
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [backgroundStates release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then in your ViewController(Remember to include your custom class) you can set the color in this way:

```
[button1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.8 green:0.7 blue:0.6 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: but i want it to change its color when clicked on. the code that you give change the color of the button(and its the same when click on)